# Form submission using ajax jquery with json encoded formate

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, database

I want to send data and file in one form through ajax jquery with json encoding. It uses MVC approach so the data from view is send back to the controller where it encodes and decodes the form_data. And then send it to the model file for insertion in database.
the coding in view  is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $("document").ready(function() {

    $("#js-ajax-php-json").submit(function() {

      var formData  = {
          "action": "test"
      };

      //data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
      formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/mvc/Controller/MainController.php", 
        data: formData,
        success: function(data) {
          $("#the-return").html(
          "Employee ID: " + data["id"] + "<br />First Name: " + data["first"] + "<br />Last Name:      " + data["last"] + "<br />City: " + data["city"] +"<br />City: " + data["country"]+"<br />JSON: " + data["json"]
                      );

          alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
  });

</script>
```

`MainController` contains the following code:

```
if (is_ajax()) {
  //Checks if action value        exists
  if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"])) { 
    $action = $_POST["action"];
    switch($action) { //Switch case for value of action
      case "test": test_function();
      case "test2":test2_function();
      break;
    }
  }
}

//Function to check if the request is an AJAX request
function is_ajax() {
  return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}


function test_function(){

  $return = $_POST;
  $return["json"] = json_encode($return);

  $json = json_encode($return);
  //echo json_encode($return);
  //$dc = json_encode($return);

  $c = json_decode($json);
  require_once '../Model/employee.php';

  $new_employee = new emp();
  $re = $new_employee->insert_employee($c);

}
```

And futher the data is forwaded to the Model file for databse insertion.
This code isn't showing any error but data it's unable to insert data in database.
Am i missing any important thing to do so???

Comment: add a console.log(formData) after this line: 
formData = new FormData($(this)[0]); and post the result.

Comment: @DavidStetler a blank row is inserted in database by writing this line.

Comment: what is the output in the console?

Comment: @DavidStetler it says "No consoles to display at this time" i mean there isn't anything displaying in console window but a blank row or record is inserted in db.

Comment: Please use chrome.  open the console, Ctrl+shift+J in windows, Cmd+Opt+J on mac.  That is where you will see the message.

Comment: @DavidStetler Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)...Console isn't showing the value for formData. Nothing happens now when i insert data the page gets refreshed automatically clearing all fields and no new record is saved in db.

Comment: And when i use  data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data); console.log('finished upload'); It saved the record successfully only error for the file type remains there. Plus the console show the message aswell.

Comment: if you are getting a 404 error, then this path is incorrect:  http://localhost:8080/mvc/Controller/MainController.php.  Make sure you can actually load that EXACT path, it is case sensitive.